# How can I add random “fuzz” to this formula, so that the randomness diminishes as values increase?

Tags: php, math, logarithm, random

I'm developing an open-ended strategy game.  I am using the following formula to calculate damage:

```
$rand = rand($a, $b) + $c;
$damage = $rand * sqrt(($d / 20) * $c));
```

`$a`, `$b`, `$c`, and `$d` are all values that can be modified by the user over the course of play, either by buying a better item (`$a` and `$b`), investing in the item (`$c`), or investing in their character `$d`.

What I want to do now is add a bit of randomness to the outcome of the equation.  However, because the game is open ended:

1. a static value would become unnoticeable/negligible over time.
2. a percentage based value would allow for too much noise over time.

So, I want to add a random value that is small at first, grows with increased input, but has diminishing returns.  I'm sure I need some kind of logarithmic formula, but I'm not sure how to go about it!

Comment: Isn't the randomnees between `$a` and `$b` via `rand` enough?  What else are you looking for?

Comment: @ircmaxell I should have explained that sometimes the `$a` and `$b` are only 1 or 2 integers apart.  The total number of possible damage values produced by this function is relative to the number of integers between the `$a` and `$b` values.  So with, say `12` and `13`, the damage returned is pretty constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you calculate your original damage as D and R is random in [-1,1], you have lots of options.  You didn't want static:

```
D = D + 1 * constant * R
```

or percentage

```
D = D + D * constant * R.
```

Something in between might be

```
D = D + sqrt(D) * constant * R.
```

Any function of D between constant and linear will give you a different balance.